# Read-only file system issue when convert and copy file to a hard drive

Tags: linux, image, yocto, dd, rootfs

I am using yocto to built **.iso** image for **x86-64 target(laptop)**, my problem is that I can't write anything in the target, it's "Read-only file system".
There is nothing provides the "read-only-rootfs" feature from yocto. When I test the same image for qemux86-64 target, it works fine.

I am using `sudo dd if=image.iso of=/dev/sdb` to create the files on the hard drive of the laptop.

Any idea how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.iso` format (ISO 9660) is read-only by design, and doesn't have a system for allocating space for new files.

Instead, you can configure Yocto to bulid a `.hddimg` file instead, which will be writable. It's described in `image-live.bbclass`:

> A `.hddimg` file which is an msdos filesystem containing syslinux, a kernel, an initrd and a rootfs image. These can be written to harddisks directly and also booted on USB flash disks (write them there with `dd`).

To bulid this format, add `hddimg` to `IMAGE_FSTYPES`.

Comment: Thanks @Justin for the reply, I tried to build an .hddimg and it fails, I added hddimg to IMAGE_FSTYPES and inherit image-live class but I got a do_bootimg error.  The error link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70755964/yocto-failed-to-buid-hddimg-error-do-bootimg