# Yocto - failed to buid hddimg. Error: do_bootimg

Tags: image, yocto

I am working on yocto,dunfell, am trying to build ***.hddimg*** image for a genericx86-64 machine. I `inherit image-live`, add `hhdimg` to `IMAGE_FSTYPES` and everything works fine with `iso`, `wic` and ... But when I add `hddimg` I get this error:

````
ERROR: test-image-1.0-r0 do_bootimg: /path/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/test-image/1.0-r0/test-image-1.0/hddimg/rootfs.img rootfs size is greather than or equal to 4GB,
ERROR: test-image-1.0-r0 do_bootimg: and this doesn't work on a FAT filesystem. You can either:
ERROR: test-image-1.0-r0 do_bootimg: 1) Reduce the size of rootfs.img, or,
ERROR: test-image-1.0-r0 do_bootimg: 2) Use wic, vmdk or vdi instead of hddimg

ERROR: test-image-1.0-r0 do_bootimg: Error executing a python function in exec_python_func() autogenerated:

The stack trace of python calls that resulted in this exception/failure was:
File: 'exec_python_func() autogenerated', lineno: 2, function: <module>
     0001:
 *** 0002:do_bootimg(d)
     0003:
File: '/path/layers/poky/meta/classes/image-live.bbclass', lineno: 257, function: do_bootimg
     0253:    if d.getVar("PCBIOS") == "1":
     0254:        bb.build.exec_func('build_syslinux_cfg', d)
     0255:    if d.getVar("EFI") == "1":
     0256:        bb.build.exec_func('build_efi_cfg', d)
 *** 0257:    bb.build.exec_func('build_hddimg', d)
     0258:    bb.build.exec_func('build_iso', d)
     0259:    bb.build.exec_func('create_symlinks', d)
     0260:}
     0261:do_bootimg[subimages] = "hddimg iso"
File: '/path/layers/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/build.py', lineno: 251, function: exec_func
     0247:    with bb.utils.fileslocked(lockfiles):
     0248:        if ispython:
     0249:            exec_func_python(func, d, runfile, cwd=adir)
     0250:        else:
 *** 0251:            exec_func_shell(func, d, runfile, cwd=adir)
     0252:
     0253:    try:
     0254:        curcwd = os.getcwd()
     0255:    except:
File: '/path/layers/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/build.py', lineno: 452, function: exec_func_shell
     0448:    with open(fifopath, 'r+b', buffering=0) as fifo:
     0449:        try:
     0450:            bb.debug(2, "Executing shell function %s" % func)
     0451:            with open(os.devnull, 'r+') as stdin, logfile:
 *** 0452:                bb.process.run(cmd, shell=False, stdin=stdin, log=logfile, extrafiles=[(fifo,readfifo)])
     0453:        finally:
     0454:            os.unlink(fifopath)
     0455:
     0456:    bb.debug(2, "Shell function %s finished" % func)
File: '/path/layers/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/process.py', lineno: 182, function: run
     0178:        if not stderr is None:
     0179:            stderr = stderr.decode("utf-8")
     0180:
     0181:    if pipe.returncode != 0:
 *** 0182:        raise ExecutionError(cmd, pipe.returncode, stdout, stderr)
     0183:    return stdout, stderr
Exception: bb.process.ExecutionError: Execution of '/path/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/test-image/1.0-r0/temp/run.build_hddimg.18514' failed with exit code 1:
WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.


ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /path/build/tmp/work/genericx86_64-poky-linux/test-image/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_bootimg.18514
ERROR: Task (/path/layers/meta-ammsc2/recipes-core/images/test-image.bb:do_bootimg) failed with exit code '1'```
````

Comment: Is this the complete error message? It seems the first few lines have been missed because it starts with ".. and this doesn't work on a FAT filesystem"

Comment: Sorry, was copy/paste fault. Now the error is complete. As I see the error is related to the rootfs size. In the `image-live.bbclass`  the hddimg rootfs.img max size is set to 4GB, and in my case it exceeds the max size. Any Idea how to fix that ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rootfs for `test-image` is larger than 4GB, which is the maximum filesystem size for `FAT` partitions (the default used by the `.hddimg` image type).

The error already contains two solutions:

1. Reduce the image size, by removing packages
2. Use the `wic` format (`vmdk` and `vdi` are for virtual machine engines)

To use the `wic` format, simply add `wic` to `IMAGE_FSTYPES` and Yocto will build a `.wic` image and place it in the `deploy/images` directory. You can flash this to your disk using `dd` or `bmaptool`, and boot it.

These images are built from a template specified by `WKS_FILE`, which defaults to `genericx86.wks.in` for the the `genericx86-64` machine. This default template creates a partition table and installs an EFI bootloader (Grub).

If you'd like to manually generate the `wic` images or modify the templates, check out the documentation for [Creating Partitioned Images Using Wic](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/dev-manual/common-tasks.html#creating-partitioned-images-using-wic).